# Join two tables. Use a joined column as Group By to then select the latest row based on timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

connector_status

| connector | status_timestamp | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-03 09:07:09.058000 | available |
| 2 | 2020-03-03 09:51:03.852000 | faulted |
| 1 | 2022-10-06 16:32:14.130000 | charging |
| 3 | 2022-10-06 16:28:26.228000 | available |
| 4 | 2022-10-06 16:28:03.195000 | charging |

connector

| connector | box_id | connector_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha | 0 |
| 2 | Alpha | 1 |
| 3 | Beta | 0 |
| 4 | Beta | 1 |

My connector_status table has multiple rows for each connector, but I only want the most recent row, based on the box_id

I would like to join the tables based on box_id but using the latest timestamp from the 2x connectors. This would select status charging based on the above table

The joined table would look a bit like this:

| connector | status_timestamp | status | box_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-03 09:07:09.058000 | available | Alpha |
| 2 | 2020-03-03 09:51:03.852000 | faulted | Alpha |
| 1 | 2022-10-06 16:32:14.130000 | charging | Alpha |
| 3 | 2022-10-06 16:28:26.228000 | available | Beta |
| 4 | 2022-10-06 16:28:03.195000 | charging | Beta |

With the desired result:

| box_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | Charging |
| Beta | Available |

I have the following code

`SELECT IF(connector_status.status = 'Charging','Charging', IF(connector_status.status ='Available','Not Occupied', IF(connector_status.status = 'Faulted','Faulted','Occupied'))) AS group_status, connector.connector_id, connector.box_id, status_timestamp FROM connector_status  JOIN connector ON connector_status.connector = connector.connector  GROUP BY connector.box_id  ORDER BY connector.box_id`

I don't know how to do the join on box_id to get the max timestamp though.

What is confusing me is if i firstly get the latest timestamp from the connector_status table and then try and join by box_id, how can i be sure that it will take the latest connector timestanmp for that box_id

Comment: @ErgestBasha I'm using version 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use row_number to get the desired result:

```
select box_id,
       status       
from (   select status,
                box_id,
                row_number() over( partition by tbl.box_id order by tbl.status_timestamp desc ) as rn
         from   (  select   status_timestamp,
                            status,
                            box_id
                   from connector_status cs
                   inner join connector c on c.connector=cs.connector 
                ) as tbl
     ) as x where rn=1 ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/1LRcbbma